Найти все простые циклы планарного графа
Возможно, это и XY-проблема, хотя лично мне так не кажется...
Имеется планарный неориентированный граф. По-сути, разбиение некоторого многоугольника на части (это и есть X :)). Задача - найти простые (фундаментальные, или как там должны называться циклы, не включающие в себя другие) циклы (читай — эти области, на которые разбита область.
Например, вот такой граф:

Мне после обработки надо что-то типа вектора векторов — {2,6,11,10},{6,11,5,7} и так далее.
Нашел похожий вопрос, но что-то ничего не понял, как оттуда вытащить то, что мне нужно.

Исходная задача: имеется N точек на плоскости, среди всех звездчатых многоугольников с N вершинами в этих точках найти таковой с минимальной площадью. Эти области - ядра возможных звездчатых многоугольников. Если я их найду, то построить их все и найти нужный будет очень простой задачей. На рисунке ядра для множества точек {1,2,3,4,5}.

По простым полигонам вот что есть, по star-shaped не вижу особо.

Какая нужна сложность? Какие ограничения на N? Я про исходную задачу.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Теоретически - чем быстрее, тем лучше. Практически - лишь бы не полным перебором :)

"Arragement of lines". По множеству точек строятся все возможные прямые через пары. Для прямых строится упорядочение. Это стандартный алгоритм. Упорядочение - планарный граф, там есть ячейки, которые вам нужны. Надо отобрать ячейки внутри выпуклой оболочки и обойти их поиском в ширину. Для каждой ячейки площадь звезды считается за константу. Прямых будет N^2, ячеек в упорядочении N^4. Это и будет сложность. Упорядочения строятся и обходятся с помощью CGAL.

@StanislavVolodarskiy При всем уважении, ничего не понял. Как я уже говорил, геометрия для меня terra incognita... Что значит упорядочение прямых? И почему оно дает все ячейки? (Кстати, если все-все, то получается лишнее: например, тогда вместо одной проверки 8-4-11-5-9 надо будет целых 5. Хотя для всех низ звездчатый один - 2-4-1-3-5-2. Ну и, как я понял, CGAL - внешняя библиотека; увы, это задание учебное, этот вариант не работает.

Упорядочение - граф образованный пересекающимися прямыми на плооскости. Все ячейки там по построению. Лишнее получается как внутри так и снаружи от выпуклой оболочки. Но это лишнее - константа в сложности. То что задание учебное - все меняет.

Как-то все сложно описывают решение. В каком формате исходные данные графа?

@DaniilLoban Пока вообще ни в каком :) - никак не могу эту $#@$@$ геометрию закодировать... Вероятно, список ребер.

Тут все зависит от задачи, в простейшем виде точка и точки которые с ней соединены например 1 и [14,8] и все это рекурсивно т.е еще для 14 и 8 тоже самое и т.д. А самое простое но не удобное алгоритмически по координатам 1 - (x:0;y:0)

@Harry А исходная задача дана полностью? Какое ограничение на N? (в свете того, что вы собирались построить все звездчатые многоугольники... или вообще все возможные, включая звёздчатые?)

@MBo Пусть задано фиксированное множество S из N точек на плоскости. Необходимо разработать алгоритм генерации звездных многоугольников, вершинами которых являются все точки заданного множества S и определить многоугольник наименьшей площади.

@MBo Но есть и такая :) - Пусть задано фиксированное множество S из N точек в E^d (d≥3). Необходимо разработать алгоритм генерации звездных многогранников, вершинами которых являются все точки заданного множества S и определить звездный многогранник наименьшего объема. Хотите? :)

Нет, не хочу, я к оптимизационным задачам плоховато отношусь ;) Пока я еще не вполне понимаю, какие варианты будут валидными, чтобы n! перестановок точек не использовать. Вот для семи точек на окружности можно получить два варианта, которые можно назвать звездными - так?, и кучу диких каракулей, которые звездными не являются.

Ну, звездный - это такой, для которого существует точка, из которой видны все вершины. Так что простроить просто: берем тоску, все вершины сортируем по углу относительно этой точки, и в этом порядке соединяем. Между прочим, проверить, звездный он или нет - сложнее, чем построить.

Граф ядер
Поставим точку (назовём её точкой ядра) внутри выпуклой оболочки. Упорядочим точки множества по углу вокруг этой точки. Соединим их ломаной - получится звёздный многоугольник. У него отыщем ядро (каждая сторона многоугольника задаёт полуплоскость, если их пересечь - будет ядро). Ядро - выпуклый многоугольник.
Пока точка ядра двигается внутри ядра, построенная конфигурация не меняется - звёздный многоугольник один и тот же, ядро одно и то же. Подведём точку к ребру ядра (конфигурация не меняется), перенесём её через ребро и остановимся бесконечно близко к ребру. Конфигурация изменилась. Из старого звёздного многоугольника надо удалить три стороны и на их место вставить три другие стороны. Ещё раз по другому: вершины старого многоугольника были упорядочены по углу. После пересечения ребра ядра, две вершины меняют порядок (и мы знаем какие это две вершины), что влияет (разрушает и создаёт заново) три стороны звёздного многоугольника.
По новому многоугольнику строится новое ядро.
Соберём ядра в граф: ядра - вершины графа, два ядра соединены ребром если у них есть общее ребро (при перемещении ядерной точки через ребро ядра из первого ядра строится второе).
В графе есть ребра, которые выводят нас за пределы выпуклой оболочки. Ядерная точка при пересечении такого ребра ядра выходит за пределы выпуклой оболочки множества точек. В этом случае новое ядро будет пустым множеством. Такие рёбра исключим из графа.
У нас есть граф, и вершина в нём. Строить целиком весь граф не нужно, у нас есть процедура поиска соседних вершин в графе (переход через ребро ядра). Этого достаточно чтобы обойти граф поиском в ширину. В каждой вершине графа известен звёздный многоугольник и его ядро.
NB Чтобы премещаться по графу (строить новые многоугольники и их ядра), точка ядра не нужна.
Сложность:

первый многоугольник и ядро: nlogn;
соседнее ядро (и многоугольник): nlogn (можно сократить до logn, но это сложно);
число вершин в графе (разных многоугольников и ядер) - n4;
вычисление площади n (при навигации по графу можно сократитть до константы).

Общая сложность n5logn.
NB Картинка в вашем вопросе имеет непосредственное отношение к графу в этом ответе. Грань на вашей картинке - ядро и вершина графа из этого ответа. Не запутайтесь в графах, их два разных. Один ваш  - картинка, второй - абстрактный, двойственный к вашему.
РСДС
Любая пара точек множества задаёт прямую, которая разбивается на отрезок между точками и два луча. Нас интересуют только лучи и только их пересечение с выпуклой оболочкой множества точек. То есть, пара точек определяет ноль (обе точки на границе выпуклой оболочки) или один (одна точка на границе) или два отрезка (обе точки внутри оболочки).
Заведём рёберный список с двойными связями (РСДС (DCEL)). Поместим в него ребра выпуклой оболочки и все выше описанные отрезки. РСДС определеляет планарный граф. Фиксируем любую грань, выберем в ней любую точку и построим звёздный многоугольник вокруг неё. Можно показать что ядро этого многоугольника совпадёт с выбранной гранью.
Другими словами, РСДС будет содержать нужный нам ядерный граф. Обойдём его в ширину вычисляя звёзды и их площади.
РСДС можно постоить за O(n4). За такое же время можно вычислить площади всех звёзд - площади "соседних" звёзд отличаются на фиксированное количество слагаемых.
Общая сложность - четвёртая степень, но требуется работать с РСДС.
P.S. Можно ли обойтись без полного перебора звёзд?

Вы предлагаете начать с произвольной точки как точки ядра, строить многоугольник, его ядро (даже не представляю, как построить пересечение всех полуплоскостей - не на бумажке, а в коде), а потом брать точку вне него и строить все заново? Тогда и граф не нужен никакой, мы так должны построить все многоугольники. Но как выбирать новую точку? Кстати, я методом Монте-Карло это все сделал за 15 минут, грубо говоря, но именно потому, что задание учебное, метод не пройдет... Так сказать, ставлю плюсик, но не в коня корм - не понимаю я ваше решение...

Послушайте, вот вы говорите, что при переходе к новому многоугольнику надо заменить три стороны (верю на слово :)) - то нельзя ли тогда просто как-то регуляризовать эту замену, чтоб обойти все многоугольники? Типа, раз просто две вершины меняют порядок, выбрать все пары вершин и менять их, отсеивая как-то те варианты, где звездный многоугольник не получается? Черт, не могу правильно сформулировать, что хочу...

P.S. Как строить многоугольник для точки внутри оболочки, саму оболочку, как считать площадь - это я сделал. А вот дальше... Уперся даже в то, что не понимаю, какую структуру данных использовать. Точка - ясно, а дальше? Вектор точек? Как-то все время надо их отличать, - нумеровать? Точки оболочки отличать от внутренних - еще один флаг? Отрезки как пары точек? А луч? вобщем, одно непонимание на самом базовом уровне... Пока на бумажке рисуешь - вроде понятно. Садишься кодировать - полный ступор... Злюсь на самого себя, но деру из интернета, ту же оболочку сам написать не смог...

Если я вам дам выпуклый многоугольник и полуплоскость вы его отрежете этой полуплоскостью просто проверяя вершины многоугольника, слева они или справа от прямой-границы полуплоскости. В качестве старта берём квадрат содержащий все вершины множества. Теперь у вас есть алгоритм: по набору полуплоскостей построить их пересечение.

Это пересечение - ядро. Каждое ребро ядра задано стороной звездного многоугольника. Если мы пересекаем это ребро ядра, соотсветствующее ребро звездного многоугольника переворачивается. Вот новый многоугольник. Так и бродите по ним.

Понимаете, на бумажке я это все могу нарисовать и показать, как. Закодировать - ступор. Как считать это пересечение? Какие структуры данных? Что получается в результате? В какой-то момент бесконечного размера фигура становится конечной - как это отрабатывается? Ну нет у меня опыта работы с геометрией, а в анамнезе, так сказать, одна заброшенная лет 25 назад задача, где должны были сыграть полиэдры Вороного, но я так и не придумал, как их описать (вопрос был даже не в эффективном алгоритме). Не моё, увы. Сейчас бьюсь скорее из принципа, но, похоже, пора признать поражение...

Бесконечной фигуры нет, начните с большого прямоугольника. Структура для многоугольника - список вершин. Ребро - пара соседних вершин. Ребро разрезается если его концы в разных полуплоскостях. Я готов набросать код. Какой язык?

Да так вам придется все писать :), какой смысл? Ну напишу, а дальше? Lfkmit будет что-то из той же серии, где надо будет искать, например, нет ли - пройдя по кругу - общей стороны с уже пройденным или, например, куда поворачивать... Вобщем, не стоит оно того.

Я преподаю вычислительную геометрию. Мне интересны приложения, которые, честно говоря, редко попадаются. Ваша задача новая.

Если у вас есть координаты узлов и список ребер, то можно поступить так:
Вместо каждого ребра образуем две дуги (направленные рёбра), например, 1-8 и 8-1.
Возьмем нижнюю левую точку. Обходим внешнюю грань против часовой стрелки, выбирая самую правую исходящую дугу, здесь 1-8-9-3-13-7-6-2-10-12-14-1, удаляем дуги.
Берём любую дугу из оставшихся, обходим первую грань - опять же, выбирая самую правую исходящую дугу - например, 1-14-4-8-1 (помним, что 1-8 уже нет), удаляем дуги.
Повторяем для оставшихся дуг. В результате должно получиться F = E - V + 2 граней (включая внешнюю)

Но цикл 1-8-9-3-13-7-6-2-10-12-14-1 не тот, который нужен... Да и понятие влево-вправо для графа несколько странновато. Или мы в данном случае рассматриваем не столько граф, сколько именно геометрический многоугольник, и "самая правая" относится к нему?... И надо рассматривать именно правые повороты (в геометрическом смысле)? А для "просто графа" алгоритма нет?...

Да, внешняя грань вам не нужна, поэтому я её выделил отдельно. Рассматриваем именно геометрию этой фигуры, граф здесь выступает как средство организации элементов. Для просто графа есть метод поиска базиса фундаментальных циклов, основанный на минимальном остовном дереве. Но так навскидку не скажу, будет ли результат описывать нужные вам грани, или может получиться 1-8-4-14 + 1-8-4-12-14-1 вместо  1-8-4-14 + 4-12-14

Блин, как же я (еще со школы) ненавижу геометрию... а тут сплошные углы считать. Ладно, я попытаюсь, но если кто читает — предпочту решение, которое никак от геометрии не зависит! :)

Абстрактный граф ещё нужно уложить на плоскость, если он планарный - а у вас уже есть геометрическое описание укладки. Сами углы считать не нужно, косое произведение для определения взаимной ориентации дуг.

Косое — это что? В смысле, векторное? Но так мы получим только, есть ли поворот вправо, скажем. А втор для какого ребра он больше - по знаку не определим.

Да, векторное...

Например, знак и для произведения 12-4 на 4-8, и на 4-14 будет одного знака, как узнать, какое "правее"? :) Не проще atan2? Хотя как там определить корректно именно относительный угол... Да что ж такое, куда ни ткни, все время проблемы :)

Между собой 4-8 и 4-14 сравнить

можно и с atan2(a x b, a dot b) - даст относительный угол - насколько повернуть a, чтобы совместить с b (или наоборот?)

Ладно, завтра попробую заняться. У меня еще и получение графа только проработано на уровне алгоритма, но не написано :)

То, что я спросил - не метод. Я не могу построить этот граф быстро. Получается огромное количество пересекающихся отрезков, и как отловить все пересечения, да еще и каждый потом разбить на отдельные... Угрохал 4 часа, гори оно огнем. Считает эти пересечения черт знает сколько времени, при том, что Монте-Карло из 100000 построений работает порядка секунды :)
